# Github Actions - pushing a Docker container to Digital Ocean container registry creates a new Digital Ocean API key with every push

Tags: github-actions, digital-ocean

When I push my code to GitHub, I have a workflow action that sends a container to my Digital Ocean container repository. It appears that on every push, a new API key that never expires is generated in Digital Ocean, which I don't think should be happening. Does anyone know what the issue may be? Perhaps the incorrect line is `doctl registry login --access-token ${{ secrets.DIGITALOCEAN_ACCESS_TOKEN }}` (I have set this access token in my GitHub repository secrets)? This is the code for the actions workflow:

```
name: Docker Build and Push

on: push

jobs:
  build_and_push:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Setup Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: "3.x"

      - name: Install doctl
        run: |
          curl -OL https://github.com/digitalocean/doctl/releases/download/v1.94.0/doctl-1.94.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz
          tar xf doctl-1.94.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz
          sudo mv doctl /usr/local/bin

      - name: Login to DigitalOcean
        run: |
          doctl registry login --access-token ${{ secrets.DIGITALOCEAN_ACCESS_TOKEN }}

      - name: Create data directory
        run: mkdir data

      - name: Build Docker image
        run: |
          docker build --compress -t edu-data-proxy .
          docker save --output data/image.tar edu-data-proxy

      - name: Push to DigitalOcean Container Registry
        run: |
          DO_CONTAINER_REPO=${{ secrets.DO_CONTAINER_REPO }}
          if [[ "${GITHUB_REF}" == refs/heads/main ]]; then
            docker tag edu-data-proxy:latest registry.digitalocean.com/$DO_CONTAINER_REPO/edu-data-proxy:dev
            docker push registry.digitalocean.com/$DO_CONTAINER_REPO/edu-data-proxy:dev
          elif [[ "${GITHUB_REF}" == refs/tags/*-release ]]; then
            TAGGED_DO_CONTAINER_REPO=registry.digitalocean.com/$DO_CONTAINER_REPO/edu-data-proxy:$(echo ${GITHUB_REF#refs/tags/} | sed 's/-release//')
            docker tag edu-data-proxy:latest $TAGGED_DO_CONTAINER_REPO

            docker push $TAGGED_DO_CONTAINER_REPO
            docker tag edu-data-proxy:latest registry.digitalocean.com/$DO_CONTAINER_REPO/edu-data-proxy:latest
            docker push registry.digitalocean.com/$DO_CONTAINER_REPO/edu-data-proxy:latest
          fi
```